# Using options with cloud zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i use options with cloud zoom plugin. The website is http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/examples . i need to acheive the innerzoom example.

this is the javascript code i am using to call the plugin, how do i modify this code to achieve that example

```
<!-- Call quick start function. -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CloudZoom.quickStart();
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `CloudZoom.quickStart({autoInside: true});`

Comment: tnk. just tried that @Batu, it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about cloud zoom, but I would try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CloudZoom.quickStart({
        zoomPosition: 'inside',
        autoInside: true
    });
</script>
```

Inspecting the demo-site, i figured out that they used data-attributes on their examples:

```
<img alt="Cloud Zoom small image" data-cloudzoom=" zoomImage:'/sites/starplugins/images/jetzoom/large/image7.jpg', zoomPosition:'inside', zoomOffsetX:0 " src="/sites/starplugins/images/jetzoom/small/image7.jpg" class="cloudzoom">
```

Have you already tried data-attribs?

Comment: thanks julian data-attribs did the trick! how do i vote you up, i'm new

Comment: Hey, glad that it works! Voting is only possible after getting more reputation through community-activity. But you can mark this answer as the accepted answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.